# Alexa beta build issue :The 1st example phrase for en_US need to be started with 'Alexa'. In the Launch tab?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

Am trying to submit Alexa beta build to test developed skills but am getting below error can some one help? The 1st example phrase for en_US need to be started with 'Alexa'. In the Launch tab, go to Skill Preview for en_US to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the launch tab, your first example phrase should start with "Alexa,".

So it means;
for example your skill name is XYZ. Then your first phrase should be something like that:

`Alexa, open XYZ`